# Сервис contenteditable

Tags: веб-служба

Кто-нибудь знает сервис для редактирования сайта и сохранения этой отредактированной копии?

Answer (score 1):

https://koding.com/, наверно.

Но я пользуюсь Local History в WebStorm / PhpStorm

http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/local-history.html
[image]